# npm module missing files after publish

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules, npm-publish

For reference, the repo is https://github.com/microsoftly/luis-response-builder.

The node module files are generated with tsc and output to the dist folder. I have a prepublishOnly step that removes the dist folder, runs tsc, then runs the test against the transpiled js. The tests pass when I publish just fine.

The problem is, when I install the project anywhere else, the dist folder contains only the file with the path dist/src/index.js.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the file is missing when installed but not when published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [package.json documentation about `files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files).

Since you haven't included the `files` key, it will only include the file specified in `main` (along with some other default files).

The `files` value is an array so you can include multiple files and/or folders.

eg:

```
files: [
  "dist",
  "config/somefile.js"
]
```

Comment: You are right, I seem to have missed his/her `.gitignore` file. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [npm-publish Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish):

> All files in the package directory are included if no local `.gitignore` or `.npmignore` file exists. If both files exist and a file is ignored by `.gitignore` but not by `.npmignore` then it will be included.

Your repository's [`.gitignore` file](https://github.com/microsoftly/luis-response-builder/blob/master/.gitignore) contains the following:

```
node_modules
dist
*.env
yarn-error.log
```

Since `dist` is being ignored, it's not committed with `npm publish`, as per the documentation.